# What is the original formulation of "all is one"

Tags: parmenides

I couldn't find any article reporting the original formulation by Parmenides. Of course there are no direct writings, but I'd like to know what the tradition says.
First of all what is the Greek wording? We read about "*pantha rei*" and "*to ti on"*, what is the original ?
Also, did he ever complete the process with the implied "...*and one is many/all?*, and , more important, does all refer only to the physical universe or to the Absolute All?
Did he ever explain the qualities of the One? is he a god Greek know, or a new god?

Comment: The title says 'original formulation' but the question asks only about Parmenides. It would help if the title made it clear you're asking specifically about Parmenides.

Comment: @Peterj At first I too thought OP's referring to the well known advaita book [All is One](https://www.advaita.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/Ellam-Ondre.pdf).

Comment: I have not read this, but I have always found E.R. Dodds to be excellent. He is writing here of the Neoplatonic One. https://philpapers.org/rec/DODTPO-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I couldn't find any article reporting the original formulation by Parmenides.

There are extant fragments of [Parmenides' *Poem*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/parmenides/#OveParPoe); see e.g. [WikiSource](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Fragments_of_Parmenides) for the English (by John Burnet) translation:

> "The first [principle], namely, that *It is*, and that it is impossible for it not to be, is the way of belief, for truth is its companion." [Fr.2]
>
> "One path only is left for us to speak of, namely, that *It is*. In this path are very many tokens that what is is uncreated and indestructible; for it is complete, immovable, and without end. Nor was it ever, nor will it be; for now it is, all at once [*ἔστιν ὁμοῦ πᾶν*], a continuous one." [Fr.8]

---

Of course, many books are available; see e.g. John Palmer, [Parmenides and Presocratic Philosophy (Oxford University Press, 2010)](https://books.google.it/books?id=P2IqpqA9wj4C&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: have you found the original Greek for all is one? or for its qualities *Only one thing exists, which is timeless, uniform, and unchanging*

Comment: @user157860 - maybe useful for [Greek text](https://www.ellopos.net/elpenor/greek-texts/ancient-greece/parmenides-being.asp).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hope I'll find what I need